# Finding the probability that an exponential random variable is less than a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable, joint-distribution

I have the following statement I am trying to solve: Let $T$~ $exp(2)$  and let $X$ ~Uniform$(0,1000)$ , where $T$ and $X$ are independent random variables, what is $P(500 + 1200T - X < 0)$ and have gotten:

$P(500 +1200T - X < 0) = P(T < \frac{X-500}{1200}) = \int_{x=0}^{x=1000}\int_{t=0}^{t=\frac{x-500}{1200}}f_{X,T}(x,t)dtdx$

$=$ $\int_{x=0}^{x=1000}\int_{t=0}^{t=\frac{x-500}{1200}}\frac{1}{500}e^{-2t}dtdx$

Plugging this into an integral calculator gives me a negative number, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the admissible values of $X$ is $X>500$ so that $T>0$.

Comment: Can not believe I missed that, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: draw a figure. Your integration limits are wrong. It should be
$$
  \frac{1}{500} \int_{500}^{1000} \int_0^\frac{x-500}{1200}e^{-2t}dt\,dx = \frac{3}{5}e^{-5/6}-\frac{1}{10} \approx 0.1608
$$

```
n <- 10^6
X <- runif(n, 0, 1000)
S <- rexp(n, 2)
mean(500 + 1200 * S - X < 0)
[1] 0.160806
```